# Как присвоить точке координаты?

Tags: android, массивы

Как рисуя на canvas многоугольник присвоить каждой вершине имя?

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawText("A",startX-80,startY+60,paint);
        canvas.drawText("B",x[1],y[1],paint);
        canvas.drawText("C",x[2],y[2],paint);
        canvas.drawText("D",x[3],y[3],paint);
      .........
}
```

Comment: Количество углов может быть n-ым?

Comment: вы хотите рисовать букву возле каждой точнки на канве? Присваивание имен имеет немного другой смысл.

Comment: Да количество углов может быть n. Да рисовать букву возле каждой точки, и потом в дальнейшем использовать их нажимая на углы вводить диагонали или присваивать сколько градусов